# Lua - Extracting index from a string

Tags: lua

I have a lua string s1 as shown below.

```
s1='..{"login":{"username":"necs_0","url":"sip:192.168.1.218","contact":"sip:necs_0@192.168.1.218:61376","serverip":"192.168.1.216","serverport":"4080"}}';
```

First two bytes shown as .. contains two bytes for length in big endian format. Then after 
 `{"login":{"username":"necs_`  the index value **0** is present. I need to extract that index value.

I have written below script, it works. I want to know what is the best efficient way to write it.

```
s1='..{"login":{"username":"necs_0","url":"sip:192.168.1.218","contact":"sip:necs_0@192.168.1.218:61376","serverip":"192.168.1.216","serverport":"4080"}}';

-- Advance first two bytes
s2 = s1:sub(3);

-- Find the index of necs_
index1 = s2:find('necs_', 1, true);

-- Find the index of "
index2 = s2:find('"', index1, true);

-- Extract the data between necs_ and "
s3=string.sub(s2,index1+5,index2-1);

-- Print the extracted data
print(s3)
```

Few things that worries me, in `s2 = s1:sub(3)` line, s2 a new string is created and contents from s1 is copied to new string s2. In case of C, I could have done like `s2 = s1 + 2`, thereby I could have avoided copy.

Then I am using `find` and `sub` apis. Is there any better efficient option to do it.

Comment: Just `match` it: `print( s1:match("necs_(%d+)") )`

Comment: Thanks Mike. Just for my understanding, if I want to extract the value after second occurrence of necs_ , can we use match api. Or is there any better way there.

Comment: It seems that your data is JSON, is there a reason to not parse it and work on the parsed data (that would be nested tables)? Are you sure that the data fields will always appear in the same order in your string?

Comment: @Kamal If you need values after `@` then use pattern : `local id, ip, port  = s:match("sip:necs_(%d+)@(.+):(%d+)")`